# Lotus Notes - Remove icon from workspace after the opening of the .nsf

Tags: lotus-notes, formula

On my page in a main Lotus app I have 3 buttons which are opening 3 databases.

The formula code is:

```
@Command([FileOpenDatabase]; "ServerName":"Testing.nsf"; ""; ""; "1"; "1" );

@Command([WindowWorkspace]);

@Command([FileDatabaseRemove]);
```

It works, but It gives me a message: Remove selected item(s)? And I click yes and then finally it is ok. Is there any chance, to remove-it without that messagebox to appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove database icon from workspace because you already set parameter `temporary` to `"1"`. This parameter avoids creating an icon opening the database.

So, the only thing you have to do is to delete the second and third line of your code. Then your database gets open without creating an icon on workspace.

Comment: Hello! I just tried it before posting the question and the icon appeared, and now I tested again and it works! :confused: I did something wrong I guess, but I don't know what exactly, thanks again!